# Puppet does not update package after changing the repo

Tags: gitlab, puppet, rpm, yum

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#upgrading-to-gitlab-runner-10 the repos changed, so we are trying to update the gitlab-runner of all nodes. **We need to delete the old repo and add the new one and then update the package.**

On our puppet manifest[1] we update the repo, ensure the latest version of the package and after this update we have to run a script before ensuring that a service is running.
Our problem is that we should only run this script after an update.

Right now, even if the repo is updated, the package is not. The package is only updated if distro_sync runs or if we run "*yum update gitlab-runner*", never through a puppet run. It seems that the package is never updated as if it was checking the latest version of the old repo instead of comparing against the recently added repo.

[1]

```
# Installs a GitLab-CI runner for CERN GitLab
class gitlab::gitlab_ci_runner (
  String $ensure = 'latest', # passed to the gitlab-runner package. Can be used to force a version
) {
  ensure_resource('yumrepo', 'gitlab-runner', {
      descr    => 'gitlab-runner for EL6/7',
      baseurl  => "http://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/el/${::operatingsystemmajorrelease}/${::architecture}",
      gpgcheck => 0,
      enabled  => 1,
      exclude  => absent,
  })

  ensure_packages(['gitlab-runner'], {
    ensure  => $ensure,
    require => Yumrepo['gitlab-runner'],
  })

  exec {"post-install":
    command => 'sudo /usr/share/gitlab-runner/post-install',
    provider => shell,
    onlyif  => 'test -e /usr/share/gitlab-runner/post-install',
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe => Package['gitlab-runner'],
  }

  service { 'gitlab-runner':
    ensure  => running,
    enable  => true,
    require => [Package['gitlab-runner'], Exec["post-install"]]
  }

}
```

Comment: This is probably because the `ensure => <value>` is evaluated by resource prefetching so that the repo metadata for the latest version is processed prior to catalog application. Therefore, the repo subscription change does not affect the `ensure => latest` of the package resource as it occurs during application after prefetch. While this is very probable, I cannot definitively say this is the case so i leave this as a comment.

Comment: @MattSchuchard That was exactly the problem, specifying a version did work. Do you know if there is any way to refresh the metadata? In any case please feel free to give this explanation as a response.

Comment: Not a great workaround, but if it updates the package to the latest on a consecutive catalog application, then my theory becomes more likely to be correct. Ok, never mind, I just found the source code to verify my theory.

Comment: Could you link the source code? In any case yes, consecutive puppet runs work as expected, so I would say it is a workaround unless there is some way of forcing the refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this behavior is because puppet is prefetching the repository metadata for the package resource prior to catalog application of resources. Note the relevant source code for the current state of the source code [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/ba4d1a1aba0095d3c70b98fea5c67434a4876a61/lib/puppet/provider/package/yum.rb#L28-L58) for yum and [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/ba4d1a1aba0095d3c70b98fea5c67434a4876a61/lib/puppet/provider/package.rb#L3-L9) for the general provider. Note that the broad functionality of the linked code has not changed over time, so while the subtleties may change, the overall behavior has/will not.

Due to this, the determination of the `latest` version of a package occurs prior to the application of the resource. Therefore, in your situation the repositories you are subscribed to at catalog compilation will determine the `latest` version of a package. Your repository subscription change during catalog application will not impact the behavior of `ensure => latest`.

As you can probably guess, ensuring a specific version will still have the desired effect as it will utilize the new repository and no resource prefetching regarding `latest` occurs (other prefetching does still occur). Alternatively, a consecutive catalog application will have the desired effect for `ensure => latest`. To summarize, your workaround options here are:

- Apply the Puppet catalog twice in succession.
- `ensure => <version>` where you specify an exact version or version-release, such as `10.0.5-el7`.

As one can expect, a great additional source of information about resource prefetching is Gary's blog article [here](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/12/15/seriously-what-is-this-provider-doing/). Scroll down to the title that begins with "Prefetching, flushing, caching, and other". Note the normal caution about Gary's blog having "strong language". The official documentation for it is essentially useless.

Comment: Applying puppet apply twice does not make the package update, only ensuring a version does (Using sl6).

Comment: I'm confused, @djuarez.  In an earlier comment on the question itself, you seemed to say that performing two consecutive runs resulted in the package update being performed.  Here, however, you seem to be contradicting the earlier comment.  I would very much expect that if one run successfully updated the repository configuration then a second that ensures your packages "latest" would apply any appropriate package update.  If that's in fact not happening then you must have something more subtle going on, probably outside of Puppet itself.

Comment: 1- Run with ensure => <version> 2- ensure => 'latest'. This ensures any update. Running twice with ensure => <version> does not, sorry for the misunderstanding.